# function context issue in javascript - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have got very interesting issue in following code:

This works (something in proxyLoginSuccess throws error because it fires out of context I think):

```
this.model.save()
    .done(this.proxyLoginSuccess)
```

but this doesn't

```
this.model.save()
    .done(function() {
        this.proxyLoginSuccess();
    })
```

proxyLoginSuccess is:

```
this.proxyLoginSuccess = options.loginSuccess;
```

I have got context issue here, not sure how to fix this, appreciate any clues?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the context with which the function is run using underscore,

```
this.model.save()
.done(_.bind(function() {
    this.proxyLoginSuccess();
}, this));
```

Or with jQuery,

```
this.model.save()
.done(Backbone.$.proxy(function() {
    this.proxyLoginSuccess();
}, this));
```

Or by keeping a reference to your local scope,

```
var self = this;
this.model.save()
.done(function() {
    self.proxyLoginSuccess();
});
```

Or Natively ([MDN Polyfill for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)),

```
this.model.save()
.done(function() {
    this.proxyLoginSuccess();
}.bind(this));
```

There are probably more ways, but I prefer the first option.

Comment: Or using [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you're not worried about stone age browsers.

Comment: @muistooshort good addition, thankfully MDN has a polyfill to the rescue.